# How to get started making a virtual device in Linux

Tags: linux

I want to create a virtual device in Linux with various functions that execute given temporarily defined configuration, and even on inspection of the data itself. I want this to be presentable as a block device to a KVM instance. Where could I get started learning how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start looking at this documentation [An introduction to block device drivers](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/2890)

The best book is Linux Device Driver version 3, which is quite old now, but, a new release will happen very soon.

[Linux Device Drivers, 4th Edition](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920030867.do)

Answer (score 0):

You can use losetup to create virtual block devices on Linux:

```
losetup filename
```

will create `/dev/loop0` which reads and writes from `filename`. The size of the device is the same as the size of `filename`.

You can inspect the data by watching the file.